# Is there a way to press the numpad 7 key, either in pyautogui or or via hardcoding in python?

Tags: python, forms, pyautogui

I am trying to write a program to automatically fill in a form in a UNIX simulator (WRQ Reflection) which requires me to press the numlock key, followed by num7 to enter. However when I run the below code, my program just types the number 7 into the field instead of proceeding as if I've physically pressed the two buttons:

```
pyautogui.press('1')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('5')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('1')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(0.1)

pyautogui.typewrite(['tab','tab'],0.1)

Product_Class = list('MERGE[enter image description here][1]')
Product_Code = list('1A309')
Vessel_Number = list('14X')
# Fills the product class field (usually MERGE)
i = 0
PCend = len(Product_Class) - 1
while i<=PCend:
    pyautogui.typewrite([Product_Class[i]])
    i+=1
time.sleep(0.4)
pyautogui.press('tab')
# Fills the product code field (This is the user entered merge number)
i = 0
Mend = len(Product_Code) - 1
while i<=Mend:
    pyautogui.typewrite([Product_Code[i]])
    i+=1
time.sleep(0.4)
pyautogui.press('tab')
# Fills the vessel number field (This is the user entered spinning machine)
i = 0
VNend = len(Vessel_Number) - 1
while i<=VNend:
    pyautogui.typewrite([Vessel_Number[i]])
    i+=1
time.sleep(0.4)
pyautogui.press('tab')
# Prints the SOC to screen
pyautogui.keyDown('numlock')
pyautogui.press('num7')
```

Comment: Did you tried `pyautogui.press("numlock")`

Comment: Yes it registers the numlock press (i.e. it turns on/off) but then it doesn't press 7 on the numpad, it just prints '7' in the form field